# How to produce multiple DC voltages for a single project with different dc requirements

Tags: power, electronics, voltage

I have a project that has 2 12V .2 amp fans, and 1 30 3 amp LED COB panel, and a 5 V Arduino. I was wondering if there was a simple method to power all of these devices from a 120 V wall outlet?

As of right now considering a 30 volt AC to DC power supply. Then a series of switch buck converters. Or something along these lines.

Thanks for the help.(also I realize there was a similar post before but wanted some additional insight)

Comment: what is a `1 30 3 amp LED COB panel`?

Comment: Assume "1 30 3 amp" is actually "1 30 volt 3 amp".  You can do what you said.  You can use 3 independent power supplies ... as long as you connect the grounds together (nitty gritty: As long as they are either all floating or the negative lead is ground).  But, wow, 30 volt 3 amp LED???  You sure that's a voltage regulated power supply?  Or is that a current regulated power supply?  If the latter ... well, that puts into question all our assumptions and solutions.

Comment: This is better asked on [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

If it wasn't for the LED panel then I'd say use a mains to 12V DC power supply. You can then get small off the shelf switching regulator modules that with the addition of a couple of capacitors will reduce that down to 5V for the arduino.

If you genuinely need 3A at 30V (90 Watts of LEDs? That's a LOT of light) then use a compatible mains supply for that.
You can get off the shelf switching modules that will drop from ~30V down to 12V 1A, they are a little more expensive than 12V to 5V parts, mainly because it's a less common requirement, but a quick search on RS shows up some options for around $15.